# Write Oracle SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle11g

how to rank each country based on number of people in SQL.

Comment: One way to do this is to write a query. Or have you figured this out already? Then how far have you got? Where are you stuck? Show what you have. Explain the issues you are facing.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT country, count(people) as count FROM your_table GROUP BY country 
) ORDER BY count DESC
```